# Select / move boxes

Tags: macos, pages

I've imported a document from Word. I have a problem removing the imported page numbers and adding mine. This is what I got:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/P548W.png]

The rightmost "6" is the one coming from Word. I can't get to select it (in order to delete it). The other 6 is the one I added as page number, but I don't know how to move the containing box upward.

Any help?

**EDIT**: Here is the file: http://jumpshare.com/v/j7UKl0?b=to1t8

Comment: Can you upload the document? Erase all personal content and leave the problematic parts intact.

Comment: patrix has already given the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice one, see screenshot for option to make the page number from Word editable:

[image]

The box is actually the footer, to move it upwards open the Info window (<kbd>Opt-Cmd-I</kbd>), go to the Document properties (first icon) and change the footer boundary.